# Generic extends Events.EventEmitter

Tags: typescript

Thanks to WebStorm, I get the following error over and over again:

```
Error:(6, 9) TS2322:Type 'AnotherRandomClass' is not assignable to type 'A'.
```

Does someone has an idea why? The script's still compiling and executing without any errors, but WebStorm keeps throwing this specific error.

**AnotherRandomClass.ts**

```
import * as Events from "events";

export default class AnotherRandomClass extends Events.EventEmitter {
    static instance: AnotherRandomClass;

    constructor() {
        super();
        AnotherRandomClass.instance = this;
    }

    public static getInstance(): AnotherRandomClass {
        return AnotherRandomClass.instance;
    }
}
```

**RandomListener.ts**

```
import * as Events from "events";
import AnotherRandomClass from "./AnotherRandomClass";

export default class RandomListener {
    public getBaseClass<A extends Events.EventEmitter>(): A {
        return AnotherRandomClass.getInstance();
    }
}
```

**tests.ts**

```
import AnotherRandomClass from "./AnotherRandomClass"
import RandomListener from "./RandomListener";
import * as Events from "events";

new AnotherRandomClass();

console.log(AnotherRandomClass.getInstance() instanceof Events.EventEmitter);
console.log(new RandomListener().getBaseClass());
```

**result of tests**

```
λ node tests.js
true
AnotherRandomClass {
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using generics when you don't have to. When you say that type A extends Events.EventEmitter A could be any number of types. As a generic parameter you could pass anything to that method. You could remove the Type argument  and simply say that getInstance returns Events.EventEmitter.

```
class Base { }
class Sub extends Base {
    static instance = new Sub();
}
class Getter {
    static getClass<T extends Base>():T {
        //error Sub.instance is of type Base but not necessarily T
        return Sub.instance
    }
    static getNonGeneric(): Base {
        return Sub.instance
    }
}
```